# JRebel can't find mysterious springframework class JrBeanEventListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, jrebel

I an trying to use JRebel to run jboss with a spring boot application. Without JRebel it runs fine, but with JRebel I get this failure message:

```
JRebel: ERROR Class
'org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories' could not
be processed by org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.springdata.cbp.RepositoriesCBP@org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@21cb7d09: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/JrBeanEventListener
```

Ordinarily, I would just figure out what jar contains the JrBeanEventListener and try including it in war file, but I can't find it.  If I google for JrBeanEventListener I get 0 results (I think that might be a first time, for me)!

Anyone know what's going on?  What is JrBeanEventListener and why does JRebel want to load it?

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
JRebel: ERROR Class 'org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.springdata.cbp.RepositoriesCBP@org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@21cb7d09: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/JrBeanEventListener
     at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.springdata.cbp.RepositoriesCBP.addBeanEventListener(RepositoriesCBP.java:44)
     at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.springdata.cbp.RepositoriesCBP.process(RepositoriesCBP.java:36)
     at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(SourceFile:79)
     at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.va.a(SourceFile:376)
     at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.va.a(SourceFile:365)
     at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.va.a(SourceFile:322)
     at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(SourceFile:35)
     at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.sm.transform(SourceFile:106)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:356)
     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:435)
     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76)
     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:611)
     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:188)
     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
     at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter.<init>(DomainClassConverter.java:46)
     at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.addFormatters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:93)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addFormatters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:80)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addFormatters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:77)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:594)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdfc6380.CGLIB$mvcConversionService$31(<generated>)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdfc6380$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dcda3ae8.invoke(<generated>)
     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdfc6380.mvcConversionService(<generated>)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:389)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdfc6380.mvcConversionService(<generated>)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:566)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:432)
     at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:526)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:384)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdfc6380.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$4(<generated>)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdfc6380$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dcda3ae8.invoke(<generated>)
     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdfc6380.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
     at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
     at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
     at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
     at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
     at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
     at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.JrBeanEventListener from [Module "deployment.subscriptionService.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196)
     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
     ... 92 more
```

Comment: `JrBeanEventListener` is a class that JRebel adds as a part of Spring integration. This looks like some kind of classloading issue. I recommend you to reproduce the issue with [trace-level logging enabled](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/sendinglogs.html) and send the logs to support@zeroturnaround.com.